# Emails not sending when the number of users emails more than 300

Tags: php, wordpress

I create a functional PHP in WordPress.
when publishing an article i send it to our subscribers.
i have in DB in addition 1000 email subscriber but when i execute the function it sends only 300 emails.

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'wp_post_published_notification', 10, 2 );

function wp_post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) {
    $img=get_the_post_thumbnail( $ID, 'full' );
    $link=get_permalink($ID);
    $title=$post->post_title; 

    if($title && $img)
    {
      global $wpdb;
      $list_email = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_es_emaillist` ");

      $content="............";
      $subject="............";
      $headers="............";

      foreach ( $list_email as $email )
      {
           wp_mail($email,$subject,$content,$headers);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would guess it's a script execution time limit set by your server or a email limit set by your hosting provider.

Comment: Changed to cron since most hosting limits php script execution time for security purpose.

Comment: thanks Joseph_J  for solution